# How to select different git repos(main & forked) in groovy Jenkinsfile to run Jenkins2.0 job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have a Jenkinsfile which is used by Jenkins2.0 to run on a GitHub repo when code is merged the job will checkout the code, run unit tests and build it.

I want to use the same Jenkinsfile on forked GitHub repo but only want to checkout the code and build the code.

```
import hudson.model.*;

stage('Checkout') {
    node{
        git branch: '<BRANCH_NAME>', credentialsId: '<JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID>', url: 'git@<URL_OF_REPOSITORY>'
    }
}

stage('Test'){
    node{
        "run unit tests"
    }
}

stage('Build'){
    node{
        "build project"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the test section and add your own forked git clone url

```
import hudson.model.*;

stage('Checkout') {
    node{
        git branch: '<BRANCH_NAME>', credentialsId: '<JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID>', url: 'git@<URL_OF_YOUR_FORKED_REPOSITORY>'
    }
}

stage('Build'){
    node{
        "build project"
    }
}
```